# How to connect to Apache Cassandra with JDBC?

Tags: cassandra, jboss, netty, cqlsh, nosql

I'm trying to connect to Cassandra from Java code using JDBC connection. Here are the jars I'm using
[image]

Now this is the code which I found in the Stackoverflow to do this:

```
String serverIP = "localhost";
String keyspace = "mykeyspace";

Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
          .addContactPoints(serverIP)
          .build();

Session session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM users";




for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
      System.out.println(row.toString());
    }
```

But unfortunately it's throwing following exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.<init>(IIIIIZ)V
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Frame$Decoder.<init>(Frame.java:130)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$PipelineFactory.getPipeline(Connection.java:795)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:212)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:93)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:432)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:216)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:171)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1104)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:121)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:198)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:226)
    at com.mabsisa.resources.Demo.main(Demo.java:28)
```

I search in the internet for this exception scenario. But not much information I found. Please help me in solving this issue as I need to fix this issue as early as possible...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the netty version you are using. You are using the version 2.3.0 of netty and in that version the class

org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder

does not have the constructor which the cassandra driver needs. In the maven repository the cassandra driver core has a depedency with the version 3.9.0.FINAL of netty:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.0.2

So, try to update your version of netty.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have two version of netty lying in your final build .
I had the same problem where i had two version of netty 3.2.2 and 3.9.0 , latest datastax driver needs 3.9.0 .